# WCF REST Streamed GET response

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, rest

I have a requirement to return streamed response from WCF service.

The client would call GET on WCF REST URI and the server would send XML response when available. If no response is available, server would send a dummy XML response every few seconds to keep the connection alive.

I know this should ideally be done using Signal R (WebSockets) but I would like to know if there is a way to achieve this in WCF (without using Signal R).
I don't have to return large data, I would like to send intermittent small sized XML data.

Let me know if someone has achieved something like this with WCF REST?

Comment: So you would like to create a persistent connection between client and server using WCF? Something like this - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751463%28v=vs.110%29.aspx or http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP? Basically, you're binding is going to have a transferMode="Streaming"

Comment: Thanks  timothyclifford for looking into this. Yes, I need persistent connection between client and server after the client issues GET to WCF REST service. The examples provides are to stream large files in streamed mode. I have small XML data that needs to be streamed from server to client when they are available (just like Twitter feeds). I have transferModel set to "StreamedResponse".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how flexible you are by using WebAPI, sorry if its not what you want, but I came across this code below which is basically an api controller that pushes data back to the client on a continuous basis as HTTP response..

The client is basically a `HttpClient` which connects to a `Uri` address issuing a `GET HttpRequestMessage`. The message is sent with `SendAsync` and the stream is received as `response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()`...

Here is the link: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/bb167f0b0013#Samples/Net4/CS/WebApi/PushContentControllerSample/PushContentController/Controllers/PushContentController.cs

Comment: Thanks FatGiant for pointing me to correct direction. While I would have liked this in WCF, I have spent enough days without any success to get this work with WCF. It took me much less time to convert my project to Web API from WCF and use the sample provided.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to create a persistent connection between server and client is to use WebSockets.

WCF can use WebSockets via the [NetHttpBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh674273%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Once configured, you can force communication to always be over WebSockets via:

```
transportUsage=Always
```

Since you have a persistent connection, you will need to use [callbacks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh977020.aspx) to manage application flow when data is sent across.

There's also a [detailed article here](http://www.codemag.com/Article/1210051) describing a few different ways to create WebSocket connections in .NET (without SignalR).

[Create a WCF Service that Communicates over WebSockets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh977020(v=vs.110).aspx)